# How to change string of variable in php?

Tags: php, string, file, variables

I want to edit `string` of `variable`. But I can't make it good. The code:

```
$mysite = 'mysite'; //name of site
$myurl = 'http:/mysite.com'; //url of website
$metaauthor = ''; // meta name author;
$metatitle = 'Online CV Builder'; // meta name title
$metacopy = 'Javid Karimov'; // meta name copyright
$metakeywords = 'CV, PDF, ONLINE, RESUME'; // meta name keywords
$allowcv = '2'; // how many cv's user can create
$keyword = 'cv, pdf, resume, create cv online'; // keyword for creating security key
$mailto = 'mail@gmail.com'; // send to mail in contact php
```

I change like this(IT WORKS):

```
$str = file_get_contents('../sys/sets.php');

//replace something in the file string
$str = str_replace($mysite, $sitenamexx, $str);
$str = str_replace($myurl, $siteurlxx, $str);
$str = str_replace($metaauthor, $metaavtorxx, $str);
$str = str_replace($metacopy, $metacopyxx, $str);
$str = str_replace($metatitle, $metatitlexx, $str);   
$str = str_replace($metakeywords, $metakeywxx, $str);
$str = str_replace($allowcv, $allowcvxx, $str);
$str = str_replace($keyword, $keywxx, $str);
$str = str_replace($mailto, $mailtoxx, $str);

//write string
$wok = file_put_contents('../sys/sets.php', $str);

if($wok) {
     echo 'Changed<br/>';
 }
 else {
     echo 'Error<br/>';
 }
```

The question: If the `string` is empty (for example: `$mysite = '';` ) then it does not change. How can I solve it ? May be there is another way ? I tried the way with `fopen()`, `fgets()`, and that way I have to use `array`, but I was not able to use it.

Comment: editing a php script with php is usually a bad idea

Comment: Ok, if it is a bad idea, what advice can you give ?

Comment: I don't think trying to search a non-empty string for an empty string is ever going to work

Comment: you mean I can't change it with any ways ?

Comment: My brain >.< Ok, wait, do you mean to update `$thing` to `$thingxx`? Or `'$thing'` to `'$thingxx'`?

Comment: store the values in a db table or if you must in a file in a json string or serlised array.

Comment: want to change $thing to $thingxx

Comment: To use it in db for me is very easy. But if db stops working for a time ? what will be then ? that's why I want to use it with php. another problem is that I don't know how to do it with json or serialised array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got an empty string and try to replace it, it's not going to work, as you've found.  This is because you're trying to replace nothing with something.  As such, it would either do nothing (which it does, and is sensible) or replace every instance of nothing in the file with something, i.e. repeatedly add that something to the file until memory ran out.

To do what you're after, you should try and replace the full line, so something like:

```
$str = str_replace('$mysite = \'' . $mysite . '\';', '$mysite = \'' . $sitenamexx . '\';', $str);
```

Comment: Thanks Gabe3886. It worked. But I could not understand why it is a bad idea to edit php line with php ?

Comment: It's a bad idea to edit a php file with PHP because you could end up easily creating a syntax error which would lead to a fatal error every time a file is called which includes or requires that file.  You'd have no idea that it happened until you found and saw the error.  As others suggested, a json string or serialised array in a text file could work for you (check out json_encode and json_decode.  If you go that route, make sure the file can't be loaded in the web browser by any visitor though or you could be opening up a huge security hole

Comment: but I deny that file in .htaccess . It will not help, yes ?

Comment: denying the file in .htaccess will help, yes.  I had to state is as people will read these comments, put their config in a text file (probably config.txt) and they will be the ones who use root as their database user, and have it set up to connect from anywhere.  Their database will be stolen and they will wonder why

Comment: if I undertand right you mean that it is bad idea. and better to use json or serialise array. ?

Comment: denying access to your config files via .htaccess is a good thing.  Combine that method with json strings or serialized arrays and you won't have to worry so much about parse errors in your PHP for that part of the system

Comment: OK, I will do it. And then the editing method above will not work? So, I must write code in encoded json string in file. When I want to edit I must encode the new value in json. If I want to show it in page (f.e : $mysite) I must decode it.  I must search for json or serialize array() and how to use them while editing

Comment: if you store the data as a json string by using json_encode, you can get the array back by using json_decode t produce an array.  If you use a serialized string, you can `unserialize()` it to get back a full array to use.  There's no need for searching the string for specifics.  Revert it to an array and use the array keys you know

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much for help :)